# Finding 10-unique-digit number with i-first-digits divisible by i

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I was posed this question by a friend:

> I am a natural number written with 10 different digits such that for all \$i ∈ {1, . . ., 10}\$ the number formed by my \$i\$ first digits (from left to right) is divisible by \$i\$. Who am I?

I came up with a brute-force solution over the next hour or so (a few attempts failed) and came eventually finished with this:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# build all possible permutations
import itertools
base_number = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
perms = itertools.permutations(base_number)

# join the permutation lists into single numbers by joining each into a string
all_nums = [''.join(item[0:10]) for item in perms]

''' 
Check whether each item is divisible by i (from 10-->2) for subset of item, 
item[0:i]. For example;

    i = 10, number = 1234567890
    number[0:10]   = 1234567890 

        is this divisible by i(10)? Yes.

    i = 9, number = 1234567890
    number[0:9]   = 123456789

        is this divisible by i(9)? Yes.

    i = 8, number = 1234567890
    number[0:8]   = 12345678

        is this divisible by i(8)? No.

We do not check whether the number is divisible by 1 as all integers are 
divisible by 1.

'''  
for i in range(10,1,-1):
    legits = [x for x in all_nums if int(x[0:i])%i==0]
    all_nums = legits
    print "%-10d # of result can be divided by %d" % (len(legits),i)

print legits
```

I considered that a recursive algorithm could perform this task much more efficiently but have not considered how to actually code the pseudo-code'ish solution I was shown;

```
f(1) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
f(2) = for n in f(1):
       find solutions to i for $$n * 10 + i = 0 (mod 2)$$
       where i isn't a digit of n.
```

I welcome all feedback, but I'm specifically hoping to hear about my coding-style/practices and the algorithm I developed.

Comment: [Here](http://www.worldofnumbers.com/ninedig4.htm) the problem is solved without using a computer (search for "Unique Pandigital").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Style (and related tools)**

A few things are wrong concerning the style (mostly matter of whitespace). Python has a coding guideline called [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You can use [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) (or its [online version](http://pep8online.com/)) to check it automatically and [autopep8](http://pep8online.com/) to try to fix this automatically. You'll find various other convenient tools to check your code such as [pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint), [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) or [pychecker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyChecker/0.8.12).

**Making things more concise**

You can use `string.digits` to have all digits.

Also, you are using more variables that you actually need.

Finally, you don't need to precise `0` in your string slicing and all your permutations will have 10 characters so you don't have to try to take the fist 10 :

Your code becomes :

```
# join the permutation lists into single numbers by joining each into a string
nums = [''.join(item) for item in itertools.permutations(string.digits)]

for i in range(10, 1, -1):
    nums = [x for x in nums if int(x[:i]) % i == 0]
    print "%-10d # of result can be divided by %d" % (len(nums), i)

print nums
```

**Solution - algorithm, math, etc**

Your solution looks interesting in that sense that you iterate through less and less numbers (also, starting from 10 to remove many solutions from the very beginning is a nice touch). However, the issue is that you have to check all iterations at the very beginning and this is quite costly. Also, you keep a list of them in memory.

Let's try to do things differently.

For a start, we know that the number has to be divisible by 10. Therefore, we know that the `0` will be in last position.

```
>>> print(len(list(itertools.permutations(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']))))
3628800
>>> print(len(list(itertools.permutations(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']))))
362880
```

Your first iteration should be 10 times faster and your code is indeed roughly 10 times faster.

```
# join the permutation lists into single numbers by joining each into a string
nums = [''.join(item) for item in itertools.permutations(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])]

for i in range(9, 1, -1):
    nums = [x for x in nums if int(x[:i]) % i == 0]
    print "%-10d # of result can be divided by %d" % (len(nums), i)

print [n + '0' for n in nums]
```

Simimarly, the divisibility by 9 does not need to be checked because of the [following rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_3_or_9) (and the fact that the sum of the first 10 numbers is divisible by 9) : remove that check and you have yet another performance gain.

However, for an actual gain, you could go the other wat round : trying to build number by looking at the different candidates of length 1, 2, and so on.

Here is how I did it and it seems to be really fast :

```
cand = {0}
for i in range(1, 10):
    cand = { n for n in (10 * c + d for c in cand for d in range(1, 10) if str(d) not in str(c)) if n % i == 0}
print [n * 10 for n in cand]
```

Also, if you were to do things manually, after notificing that 0 has to be in 10th position so that the number is divisible by 10, you can notice that it leaves only 5 to be in 5th position so that the number is divisible by 5. You have 2, 4, 6, 8 left for 2, 4, 6 and 8th position and 1, 3, 7, 9 for 1, 3, 7 and 9th position. You can do this programmatically for yet another performance optimisation.

```
cand = {0}
for i in range(1, 10+1):
    r = [0] if i == 10 else \
        [5] if i == 5 else \
        [1, 3, 7, 9] if i % 2 else \
        [2, 4, 6, 8]
    cand = { n for n in (10 * c + d for c in cand for d in r if (str(d) not in str(c))) if n % i == 0}
    print(i, len(cand), cand)
print cand
```

Comment: A comment on PEP8: [know when to ignore it](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)

Answer (score 3):

Another way of approaching this problem would be to iterate over numbers instead of over divisors. It might result in a speed improvement or it might not, but it's worth trying at the very least:

```
for num in all_nums:
  if all(int(num[0:i])%i==0 for i in range(10,1,-1)):
    print "Solution: " + num
```

`all` will exit as soon as it finds a failed case, so for example with 123456789 using 7-2 as divisors would not be checked.

I'm not sure what effect this would have on speed, but it's generally better practice to iterate over an iterator, rather than saving a list to memory and iterating over it:

```
base_number = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
for strnum in itertools.permutations(base_number):
  num = int(''.join(strnum))
  #do stuff
```

You could also iterate over a generator expression that did the `join`, or use `map` in Python3. In Python2, `map` returns a list which rather defeats the point.

Finally, as far as I can tell, there was no need for slicing `item` on this line:

```
all_nums = [''.join(item[0:10]) for item in perms]
```

It would work just as well (and run a little faster) to do this:

```
all_nums = [''.join(item) for item in perms]
```

In fact, this is exactly what `map` is for (though I'm not sure how it compares in performance):

```
all_nums = map(''.join, perms)
```

There's nothing wrong with using a list comprehension there however, it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks, I should really consider running all my code through a PEP8 checker before posting it. 

I've read that [Guido considers map/lambda/reduce non-pythonic and that list-comprehensions are preferable](http://therootofborscht.wordpress.com/list-comprehensions/), but I (naively) can see two sides to the argument.

Comment: "At present, your algorithm checks numbers that have already failed another test.". That's not how I understand OP's code. Numbers gets filtered as you we go through the different values of `i`.

Comment: @Jonsay: whoops, missed the `all_nums=legits` line.